# Access Denied when using ExecuteQuery() for a Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

```
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

All I'm trying to do is to get (not edit) the list of users I'm a specific group from a Sharepoint site for an MVC app. I'm getting an Access Denied error when I run this line as an Admin. But this line runs just fine if I'm added to the Owners group.

I can also view the group lists through the Sharepoint site if I'm under one or the other or both groups via a web browser. It looks like both groups have the exact same permissions, too. What gives?

I'm unable to change anything else from the Sharepoint side as well, so this is not an option.

If it helps, I'm also using this as a tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538244(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the group through the UI as a user you need to edit the setting that allows other group members to see whos in the group

Navigate to site settings > people and group > click on your Group > on one of the menus like actions theres an option for group settings. In this settings area there are two config sections, One is to do with who can add users to the group and who can see who is in the group. Check these settings are correct.

Cheers

Truez

Comment: Huh...I didn't even realize this was an option in SharePoint. Thank you.